# Cloudera manager on docker is not working

Tags: docker, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am using cloudera quickstart vm on docker on Ubuntu 18.04LTS . While I launch the vm using run command :

```
sudo docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i -p 8888:8888 -p 80:80 cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

It correctly starts the hue service and I am able to access hue on localhost:8888.

But as mentioned on `https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart/` when I run /home/cloudera/cloudera-manager , I observe that hue has stopped working and also cloudera manager is also not accessible although I get below message on docker shell :

```
Success! You can now log into Cloudera Manager from the QuickStart VM's browser:

    http://quickstart.cloudera:7180

    Username: cloudera
    Password: cloudera
```

I tried localhost:7180 as well but no luck.

What could be the reason behind this ?

Comment: I am getting exact same error. Does anyone know any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I tried mapping the port 7180 by adding a :

```
-p 7180:7180
```

to the command, so it becomes :

```
docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i -p 8888:8888 -p 80:80 -p 7180:7180 cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

It worked for me